# `titleForHeaderInSection` seems to be called before viewDidLoad in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, viewdidload

I want to add titles to my header. These titles will be retrieved from array that is initiated in `viewDidLoad` I used the `override func titleForHeaderInSection` for this. When I run my code seems like the function has been called too early.

I added a breakpoint at the function and after I looped through my code 3 times, I'm able to see my `tableviewcontroller`.

I also added two print commands. One in `viewDidLoad` and one in `titleForHeaderInSection`. Guess what, the `titleForHeaderInSection` print is printed first.

Shouldn't this functions be called after `viewDidLoad`? And how can my problem be fixed?

this is what the code looks like:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    print("title")
    for index in tasks.indices{
            print(index)
            if section == index{
                print(tasks[index])
                return tasks[index]
            }
            return "no name specified"
        }
    return ""

}
```

The array is just a simple [a,b,c,d] and now the title of the first section is 'a' and the title of the other 3 are 'no name specified'

My viewDidLoad method looks like this:

```
var taskName = [""]
var dateStamp = [""]
var userId = [""]
var clType = [""]
var tasks = [""]
var count = 0
var countarr = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
var result = false
var dupClType = [""]
var loaded = false
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let query = PFQuery(className:"pendingTasks")
    query.orderByAscending("clType")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (object: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) in
        if error != nil{

        print ("error")
        } else {
            if let objects = object{
                self.taskName.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
                self.dateStamp.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
                self.userId.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
                self.clType.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)

                for object in objects{
                    if object.objectId != "Q8knzhSDon"{
                    self.taskName.append(object.objectForKey("taskName") as! String)
                    self.dateStamp.append(object.objectForKey("dateStamp") as! String)
                    self.userId.append(object.objectId! as String)
                    self.clType.append(object.objectForKey("clType") as! String)

                }

                }


            }


            self.tasks = Array(Set(self.clType))
            self.tasks.sortInPlace()
            self.loaded = true
            for items in self.tasks.indices{
                self.count=0
            for item in self.clType{
                if item == self.tasks[items]{
                    self.count = self.count + 1
                    self.countarr[items] = self.count

                }
            }

        }

                while self.countarr.last == 0{
                self.countarr.removeLast()

                }

        self.dupClType = self.clType
        }
        self.tableView.reloadData()

    })

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
     self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
}
```

Comment: if you are doing anything to the tableView before the VC's view is added to anything such as setting delegate/datasource then it will call the tableViews stuff before the views stuff

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. How can I make sure i'm doing 'nothing' before that time? My other override funcs are also based on arrays in 'viewDidLoad' and they work fine.

Comment: do your tableview setup in viewDidLoad? its hard to tell as cant see all the code.

Comment: i mean where you configure your TV and stuff, im guessing you configure your data in the viewDidLoad, have you considered doing it somewhere else ?

Comment: I have to download the data from Parse first and as far as I know that should be done in viewDidLoad. I will add the viewDidLoad as well.

Comment: in the end of viewdid load you reload tableView change that with dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {() -> Void in
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        })

Comment: Where did you put the `print` in `viewDidLoad`? You should know that you're executing a background task in it?

Comment: Also please give an example output for `tasks` after data loaded from parse, since your implementation of `titleForHeaderInSection` looks a bit suspicious.

Comment: Adding the dispatch function didn't had succes. I also placed a print at the beginning and end (in the dispatch_async function) of the vDL. The first is now displayed before the header function, so that should have fixed something.

Comment: With regard to the tasks array. I have an array of different categories call clTasks [a,a,b,c,c,c,d]. This one is retrieved from Parse and converted to 'tasks' with all duplicated removed [a,b,c,d]. Every item of the array is now a section with in that section the tasks belonging to that categorie. That all works fine. Only setting the header is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super. viewWillAppear (animated);

    double delayInSeconds = 5.0;
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
          //code to be executed on the main queue after delay
          self.tableView.reloadData()
     });
}
```

Comment: I added this part, but it is still not displaying the right thing.

Comment: It did do something, but in the debugger my array is still an empty one during the first 3 or 4 loops.

Answer (score 0):

Try settings `UITableView's` `dataSource` and `delegate` in `viewDidLoad` method instead of xib. It may work, just a guess.

Comment: I'm not a very experienced coder, so I'm not quite sure what you mean. I've added in my code in the edit now.

Comment: No problem. Look at this screenshot (http://imgur.com/SUqrQ0K) and select your tableview in Storyboard, Can you see the `dataSource` and `delegate`?

Comment: That is all setup right, so that shouldn't be the problem.

Comment: Cool. What I was saying is you please unlink both of these and set these in your `viewDidLoad` method by using `self.tableview.dataSource=self` & `self.tableview.delegate=self` before `self.tableview.reloadData()`

Comment: Nothing changed unfortunately. This is what my screen looks like. http://imgur.com/O10CXPg

Answer (score 0):

Apparently restarting Xcode (it crashed accidentally) solved my problem. The array is now loaded correctly before performing the `titleForHeaderInSection`.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    var kopTekst = ""
    for index in tasks.indices{
        if section == index{
        kopTekst = tasks[index]
        }
    }
    return kopTekst
}
```

I also changed the code a bit, but the intention should be the same.